# TestComplete:How to identify my application icon in the system tray Notification area

Tags: testcomplete

I need to locate my application from the Notification Area in the system tray.How can i make it work using the shortcut key Win +B  for Win7 and Win8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do with the application? Launch it? The following sample right-clicks the icon in the system tray based on the app name:

```
 //JScript
    function RightClickTrayIcon(Name, ItemName)
    {
          var p, tray, show_button;
        // Gets the tray
        p = Sys.Process("Explorer");
        tray = p.Window("Shell_TrayWnd").Window("TrayNotifyWnd");
        show_button = tray.WaitWindow("Button", "");
        show_button.Click();
        aqUtils.Delay(1000);
        // Right-clicks the application icon
        tray.Window("SysPager").Window("ToolbarWindow32", "Notification Area").
            ClickItemR(Name);
        // Selects an item from the context menu
        tray.PopupMenu.Click(ItemName);
    }
    function TestClickTray()
    {
          RightClickTrayIcon("Volume", "Open Volume Control");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tanya. I need to right click on the app icon.But i need to do it in Win7 and Win8.Will the same script work in both?

Comment: For Win 8 (installed on my machine), it works. I think it will work on Win 7 as well. Give it a try.

Comment: It works for notification area where there is a button.But how can i make it work when there is no button ?

Comment: Check whether the sample from here helps you:
http://smartbear.com/forums/f81/t86459/how-can-i-rightclick-on-my-application-icon-in/#87519